# boost serialization of graph property map

Tags: c++, dictionary, serialization, boost, graph

I am attempting to serialize a boost::graph with the following definitions:

```
 typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, boost::no_property,
                                  boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float> > mygraph_t;
    typedef boost::property_map<mygraph_t, boost::edge_weight_t>::type WeightMap;
    typedef mygraph_t::vertex_descriptor vertex;
    typedef mygraph_t::edge_descriptor edge_descriptor;


mygraph_t topoGraph;
WeightMap weightMap;
```

The problem is caused by my attempt to serialize the 'weightMap'

It is failing with the below error message even though I included what I believe to be the appropriate header file:
"boost/graph/adj_list_serialize.hpp"

```
/usr/include/boost/serialization/access.hpp:118:9: error: ‘struct boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::undirected_tag, float, float&, long unsigned int, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float>, boost::edge_weight_t>’ has no member named ‘serialize’
         t.serialize(ar, file_version);
         ^
```

Thanks very much for any assistance.

Comment: To give some value to your question, please post the relevant code snippet to show how you proceed with the serialization.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce it

Here's a version that works, online

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/45f664fa51c21f6e)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adj_list_serialize.hpp>

typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, boost::no_property,
                                          boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float> > mygraph_t;
typedef boost::property_map<mygraph_t, boost::edge_weight_t>::type WeightMap;
typedef mygraph_t::vertex_descriptor vertex;
typedef mygraph_t::edge_descriptor edge_descriptor;

#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    mygraph_t topoGraph;
    WeightMap weightMap;

    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(std::cout);
    oa << topoGraph;
}
```

Hopefully it will help you spot a difference. If not, you likely have a problem with a specific (old) version of Boost.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed to include the following file:

```
#include <boost/graph/adj_list_serialize.hpp>
```

This header file contains necessary serialization methods for loading/saving an adjacency_list<...> object in a non-intrusive mode.

Answer (score -1):

In order to serialize an object of any class, the class must provide a serialize() template function. Apparently the type adj_list_edge_property_map does not have that function. One way to solve the problem is to create a wrapper class W that stores an object of that type, and add W::serialize() which is implemented by serializing components of the weightMap. Then instead of serializing weightMap, you serialize W.

Comment: I don't think you've used Boost Serialization. You do not need to alter types to make them serializable